# How to supply an argument to an URL correctly in Django template?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create an API endpoint that accepts the argument `cc`.

The view for this endpoint in module `api` is:

```
def cc_details(request, cc):
    return JsonResponse({'cc': cc})
```

The URL is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/cc_details/<int:cc>', api.cc_details, name='cc_details'),
]
```

I am calling the URL from the template like this:

```
async function get_cc_details(cc) {
            let url = new URL("{% absurl 'core:analyzer:cc_details' %}" + "/" + cc)
            const response = await fetch(url)
            const json = await response.json()
            console.log(json)
        }
```

The custom `absurl` to return absolute URL is:

```
from django import template
from django.shortcuts import reverse

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def absurl(context, view_name):
    request = context['request']
    return request.build_absolute_uri(reverse(view_name))
```

However, when I try to navigate to the index page of my app, I get the following error:

> django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'cc_details' with
>   no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['api/cc_details/(?P[0-9]+)$']

It will work fine if I just manually go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cc_details/123` for example.

My guess is that I am not supplying the argument to the URL in JS function correctly. How can I fix that?

Comment: You can provide dummy ID and replace it after. You can setup _reverse only_ url template without parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are right that the error is in the URL in `get_cc_details`. Your URL `cc_details` is defined as having an integer in its path. When you use the template tag to generate a URL, that piece of code doesn't know that you're appending the integer onto the end. You need to include it as an [argument in the template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url). Without knowing the specifics of what's happening on the page, I'm guessing you have `get_cc_details` taking `cc` as an argument because you don't know what value of `cc` you want when the page loads, which matters because that's when Django is rendering that URL.

You need to do something along these lines:

```
url_string = {% absurl 'core:analyzer:cc_details' foobar %};
url = new URL(url_string.replace("foobar", cc));
```

Unfortunately, there's no way to use the Django template tag without this workaround because the template tag is only going to be evaluated when the page is first loaded. So, if you want a dynamic value in there, you either need to do this, or create another URL that takes no arguments just to use for the rendering (in which case your current code would work), but in that case, you also have to add in error handling to deal with someone showing up at that URL without a `cc` argument included.

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot. I guess that - for the reasons described in your answer - it would not be possible to get the URL's argument into my custom template tag and supply it to the `reverse` function like this: `return request.build_absolute_uri(reverse(view_name, kwargs={'cc': some_cc}))`?

Comment: Yeah, the only time that would work is the first time the template is rendered, so if you're doing any ajax requests, it won't work with those (unless you want to track state and refresh the page on each user action...)